# NSTextView: How to be notified when user pastes data?

Tags: cocoa, copy-paste, nstextview

I need to be notified when the user pastes data into an NSTextView in order to strip it of any disallowed data types (url links, etc).  I don't want to use NSTextStorageDelegate's textStorageDidProcessEditing: because it is called when the user is just typing.  How can I be notified of pastes only?

Comment: Why does it make a difference if one pastes an URL or types it?

Comment: If you want to strip data types, sounds likes you actually want to switch to plain text editing.

Comment: The requirements for the project are that italics and underlining need to be supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implementing the NSTextStorageDelegate method:  - `(void)textStorageDidProcessEditing:(NSNotification *)notification` captures any kind of text input.  I didn't see a slow down in processing, so i'll go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass `NSTextView` and override the [`paste:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000367-paste_) method to notify you of the paste after passing on to `super`.

Comment: I don't see how to use the paste: method.  the signature of the method is `- (void)paste:(id)sender` .  No docs on how to implement.  Probably my issue, but my answer below worked.